# VBA: Addition in cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sorting through data and need it to be formatted the same way. The input might have cells with 
6+18 
12 
3
5+14
20
And I want to make them all integers. I've written this so far:

```
If InStr(data.Cells(x, 8), "+") > 0 Then
    'Still trying to figure out this part
Else
    calc.Cells((lrcalc + 1), (col + s)).Value = data.Cells(x, 8)
End If
```

How would I add the value on the left of the "+" sign to the value on the right?

Comment: so you want 6+18+12+3+5+14+20?

Comment: To clarify: the end result should have 24, 12, 3, 19, and 20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well there is no need to check for `+`. Simply add an `=` sign in each cell and let excel calculate it ;)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        '~~> Find last row
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRow
            With .Range("A" & i)
                .Formula = "=" & .Value
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Great! And there's no downside to adding a "=" to the cells that don't need the internal addition?

Comment: Nope `=12` will give you `12`